# Problem with storing duplicate values in database with polymorphic relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have favorites functionality with polymorphic one to many relations in Laravel. I have ProfileImages, PostImages and Favorites models as well as those three tables. When for example I store post image with id 1 in favorites table it looks like this

```
id   user_id   favoritable_id   favoritable_type
1       15           1          App\Models\PostImage
```

(favoritable_id is id of post image in post_images table)

And then if I go and store another post image with the id 1, my code as it is, will return message "You already favorited this post image!" but it will store that in favorites table regardless and I need it not to. I need some way to check both favoritable_id and favoritable_type to be unique together in order this to work. If only one of them is unique and other ins't it won't work as it should. I got favoritable_id to be like that, but I can't figure out favoritable_type (I get null value). I tried this way if someone can help me or if there is some other way any help would be appreciated. Here is my code.

web.php

```
Route::post('/post/image/{postimage}/favorite', [\App\Http\Controllers\FavoritesController::class, 'postImageFavorite'])->name('post-image-favorite');
```

Controller

```
public function postImageFavorite(FavoriteRequest $request, PostImage $image, $postimage)
{
    if($request->favorite == true) {
        if(PostImage::where('id', $postimage)->first()) {
            $favorite = new Favorite();
            $favorite->user_id = $request->user()->id;
            $favorite->favoritable_type  = $image->getMorphClass();
            $favorite->favoritable_id    = $postimage;
            $favorite->save(); 

            // HERE IS CODE FOR DUPLICATE, THAT I TRIED
            $checkForDuplicate1 = Favorite::where('favoritable_id', $postimage)->exists();
            $checkForDuplicate2 = Favorite::where('favoritable_type', $favorite->favoritable_type)->exists();
            if($checkForDuplicate1 && $checkForDuplicate2) {
                return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'You already favorited this post image!'
                ]);
            }
            
                
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Post image doesn\'t exist!'
            ]);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        $model = Favorite::find($favorite->id);
        $id = $model->favoritable->post->user_profile_id;
        $other_user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $other_user->notify(new NewPostImageFavorite($user));

    } elseif($request->favorite == false) {
        $result = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('favoritable_id', $postimage)
            ->delete();

        return $result;
    }

    return response()->noContent();
}
```

PostImage.php

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Favorite::class, 'favoritable');
}
```

Favorites.php

```
public function favoritable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: why not put a composed unique key for these three columns?

Comment: @kuh-chan What exactly do you mean, like another id? can you show me an example?

Comment: You can define an unique key like `$table->unique(['user_id', 'favoritable_id', 'favoritable_type'])` in a migration file for the table. But aside from that - you save your model before you check for duplicates. So put the line with `$favorite->save()` behind the if.

Comment: @kuh-chan And what do I need to change in controler except to put it in behind if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check before creating a new favorite record.

```php
public function postImageFavorite(FavoriteRequest $request, PostImage $image, $postimage)
{
    //Handle when $request->favorite = false
    if($request->favorite == false) {
        $result = Favorite::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('favoritable_id', $postimage)
            ->delete();

        return $result;
    }

    //$request->favorite = true

    //Check if a PostImage record exists for the $postimage
    $postImage = PostImage::where('id', $postimage)->first();

    if(is_null($postImage){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Post image doesn\'t exist!'
        ]);
    }

    //There exists a valid PostImage record for given $postimage

    //Respond if the user has already favorited the PostImage
    if(
        $postImage->favorites()->where([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'favoritable_id' => $postImage->id,
            'favoritable_type' => PostImage::class
        ])->count()
    ){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'You already favorited this post image!']);
    }
    
    //Create a new record in favorites table to mark the PostImage as favorited by user
    $favorite = $postImage->favorites()->create(['user_id' => auth()->id()]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $model = Favorite::find($favorite->id);
    $id = $model->favoritable->post->user_profile_id;
    $other_user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $other_user->notify(new NewPostImageFavorite($user));

    return response()->noContent();
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works now, it populates the database correctly, but I have one problem. For some reason on line where is  $model = Favorite::find($favorite->id); it shows error undefined variable $favorite and it breaks it doesn't send notifications.

Comment: Sorry my bad didn't assign the newly created favorites record to variable $favorite. Have updated the answer with `$favorite = $postImage->favorites()->create(['user_id' => auth()->id()]);`

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!